# What software provides a code editing environment on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, software-recommendation

I am seeking recommendations for code editing primarily in Java, C, C++

My research shows these as candidates to meet this need:

1. Coda - iOS app for code editing and SSH (runing the code on remote computer) - it’s not clear how C or C++ would fit in coda, though.
2. Blink SSH - iOS app for Mosh or SSH to control a remote computer (I can use git for moving the files), look like linux terminal but this means I’m not using iOS as the IDE and just as a window to remote to another computer

Am I missing options to have an actual environment for editing on iOS bu restricting myself to these two options. Coda as an IDE or SSH (there are many, but they all end up needing a connection to a server)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I’ve edited this to avoid having it closed, but we might need you to describe a little where the code will run and if you are OK with constant network connection or really just need an IDE. You will get recommendations for both, but this might be two questions or three questions in the end based on a) what source version control you use b) where the code will run and what CI/CD/build process you choose c) your budget and your development style. The last one is the biggest factor. People coded on paper and punch cards for decades, why choose iPad for your needs?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/dk/app/jvm-programming-language/id486207896?mt=8 might be an option

Answer (score 2):

A good code editor for iPad is [Textastic](https://www.textasticapp.com). Its not free and sells for $10 at the AppStore.  It claims to have syntax highlighting for over 80 languages. If you want to program exclusively in Python, there is an app called [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/). This is more of an IDE than just a code editor.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a curated list - [Powerful Apps for Developers](https://itunes.apple.com/us/story/id1274797291)

Here are my “go to” apps for my iPad Pro - I do use it to screen mirror to and from a MacBook and typically travel / work with both equally, there’s still where the macOS experience is so much more productive than iOS.

[image: several IDE and code related apps]

The only ones I would consider IDE are Coda, Pythonista and Playgrounds but working Copy and Drafts are amazingly productive for me. If you don't want to take along a Mac, you'll need a network or a raspberry pi / small linux computer to do real off the grid development if iOS is your main hardware to type and code.